# **MySql** Select Before After Row For Each GroupId

Tags: mysql, sql, row, unix-timestamp, before-filter

How can I have for each grp_id 2 rows:
before and after row of current unix timestamp,

```
+---------+--------------------+------------+-------+
| id      |             grp_id |     utimes | value |
+---------+--------------------+------------+-------+
| 4156187 |               5282 | 1455663600 | 15897 |
| 4159888 |               5282 | 1455630000 | 26998 |*
| 4156190 |               5282 | 1455676200 | 28497 |
| 4156186 |               5282 | 1455661800 | 14097 |
| 4156183 |               5282 | 1455652800 |  5097 |
| 4156184 |               5282 | 1455656400 |  8697 |
| 4156185 |               5282 | 1455660000 | 12297 |
| 4156182 |               5282 | 1455651000 |  3297 |*
| 4163311 |               7216 | 1455693000 | 45297 |
| 4163275 |               7203 | 1455681600 | 33897 |
| 4163309 |               7214 | 1455697800 | 50097 |
| 4163308 |               7214 | 1455696000 | 48297 |
| 4163307 |               7214 | 1455694200 | 46497 |
| 4163306 |               7214 | 1455692400 | 44697 |
| 4163305 |               7214 | 1455690600 | 42897 |
| 4163304 |               7214 | 1455688800 | 41097 |
| 4151121 |               4356 | 1455703200 | 55497 |
| 4163271 |               7205 | 1455685500 | 37797 |
| 4163272 |               7205 | 1455687000 | 39297 |
| 4163269 |               7205 | 1455684900 | 37197 |
| 4163273 |               7205 | 1455687300 | 39597 |
| 4163264 |               7206 | 1455674400 | 26697 |
| 4163270 |               7205 | 1455685200 | 37497 |
+---------+--------------------+------------+-------+
```

```
Example:
unix-timestamp : 1455647703
```

```
+---------+--------------------+------------+-------+
| id      |             grp_id |     utimes | value |
+---------+--------------------+------------+-------+
| 4159888 |               5282 | 1455630000 | 26998 |
| 4156190 |               5282 | 1455651000 | 28497 |
| 4159889 |               XYZ  | 1455630000 | 26998 |
| 4156191 |               XYZ  | 1455651000 | 28497 |
| 4159883 |               ABC  | 1455630000 | 26998 |
| 4156195 |               ABC  | 1455651000 | 28497 |
+---------+--------------------+------------+-------+
```

Thank you !

Comment: please provide an expected output. and what did you achieve yourself already?

Comment: I think the correct output is the one marked with an asterisk. This means the second record of the result set at the end is incorrect.

Comment: what do you mean saying: "before and after row of current unix timestamp"? do you want to have rows with minimum and maximum "utimes" for each "grp_id"?

Comment: no @MaxU, for first row found "utimes <= current_timestamp" and second row "utimes > current_timestamp" for each grp_id in one time..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `LEFT JOIN` operation. The `ON` clause contains the 'business logic':

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 
   ON t1.grp_id = t2.grp_id 
      AND 
     ((t1.utimes < 1455647703 AND t2.utimes < 1455647703 AND t2.utimes > t1.utimes)
       OR
      (t1.utimes > 1455647703 AND t2.utimes > 1455647703 AND t2.utimes < t1.utimes))
WHERE t1.grp_id = 5282 AND t2.id IS NULL
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71da9/4)

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
work fine with the grp_id =5282..

But Can I apply this for all distinct grp_id?

Comment: @c0rnw19 Yes, you can. Simply omit `t1.grp_id = 5282` from the `WHERE` clause. Check [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71da9/5).

Comment: Thank you very much.
But I have about 100.000 row and it's take very long times.. :(